# Generic type incompatibility

Tags: java, generics, jooq

I have an issue with generics types on class using JOOQ.

```
public abstract class BaseDataAccessObject<T extends BaseDataClass, U extends UpdatableRecord> {

    protected abstract RecordMapper<U, T> getRecordMapper();

    public T insert(T data) throws Exception{

        //Some code ...

        U record = getRecord(data);
        record.store();
        return record.map(getRecordMapper()); // <-- PROBLEM HERE !
    }
}
```

Map accept one parameter of this type `RecordMapper<Record, E>` and it return an object of type `E`.

I face this issue :

```
Error:(110, 22) java: method map in interface org.jooq.Record cannot be applied to given types;
required : org.jooq.RecordMapper<org.jooq.Record,E>
found : org.jooq.RecordMapper<U,T>
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E argument mismatch; org.jooq.RecordMapper<U,T> cannot be converted to org.jooq.RecordMapper<org.jooq.Record,E>)
```

I don't understand why because :

- Generic `U`, inherits form `UpdatableRecord` who inherits from `org.jooq.Record`, then `U`should be compatible with `org.jooq.Record`.
- `E` should be compatible with `T` (no ancestor is defined).

I have to keep the `U` extending `UpdatableRecord`.

Comment: What is the signature of `getRecordMapper()`?

Comment: *"Map accept one parameter of this type `RecordMapper<Record, E>`"* If you mean the method you're calling as `record.map`, what does it *return*?

Comment: @marstran: The declaration of `getRecordMapper` is shown above (third line of the source, `protected abstract RecordMapper<U, T> getRecordMapper();`).

Comment: Ah, oops. Didn't see it. :P

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : It return a type `E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Record.map(RecordMapper)` method was a mistake from early days in jOOQ. It makes absolutely no sense at all to have a `map` method on a non-monadic type, i.e. on a non-wrapper type. E.g. `Stream.map()` is perfectly fine, because a stream can map its contents to something else, producing another stream. `Optional.map()` is perfectly fine, because an optional can map its contents to something else, producing another optional.

But an item / value shouldn't be able to map itself. There would have been a slight possibility to rectify this by using recursive generics, [but that would have been an even bigger mistake](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/06/28/the-dangers-of-correlating-subtype-polymorphism-with-generic-polymorphism/).

But luckily, here's the solution to your problem, and it's really easy:

```java
    U record = getRecord(data);
    record.store();
    return getRecordMapper().map(record); // <-- PROBLEM HERE NO MORE !
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all these explanation ! I had the answer under the eyes...